# Aisha's age in the book of Ibn Saad

Tags: hadith, nikah, children, aisha, age

Salam.

Is it true that Ibn Saad in Tabakat wrote that Aisha was 9 years old at the time of the engagement, and 12 years old at the time of consummation?

Similar things are written about Ibn Hillikan.

Comment: And is ibn Sa'ad more reliable than al-Bukhari, Muslim or any hadith scholar?

Comment: This is not the point.
I wanted to know if this is true, because this is interesting information.
Do you know the answer to this question?

Comment: Hear you say "*are written about*" and in a comment you say "*in one scientific book*".  The question might get better responses if it gave explicit references to what these vague expressions refer to, and actual quotations from them.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such statement.

There is agreement of all classical scholars that our mother Sayyidah Áāyishah, may Allāh be pleased with her, was 6/7 lunar years at the time of nikāh and 9 lunar years at the time of consummation.

Comment: Are you sure about this?
I met this information in one scientific book.

Comment: Yes, there is no such opinion among classical sources.

Comment: Ok, ok, thanks!